# Macro replacement for assignment from map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, macros

This (or similar) sometimes seems convinient:

```
#define ITEM_GET(variable,map) variable=map[#variable]
//...
double foo;
std::map<std::string,double> variables;
ITEM_GET(foo,variables);
```

Can I do this without a macro using some kind of template? Is this shorthand bad practice?

Comment: `foo=variables["foo"];` is less characters though...

Comment: @Pubby 1. Depends on the length of identifier `foo`. 2. You have to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily say it's bad practice, but you must make sure the pros outweigh the cons. I would suggest leaving the scope of this macro at a bare minimum. E.g., if you only do these operations during loading, limit the existence of the macro to inside the load-related functions.

If your task is such that this operation is extremely common, providing the macro seems like a sensible option. If it's just for occasional convenience, I feel the general misbehaviour of macros (mainly no scope) is not worth it.

As to your first question, there's no way to do this without a macro. No translation stage later than the preprocessor has access to a tool equivalent to the stringise operator `#`.